# student-t sampling with fractional degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to generate random samples from a Student-$t$ distribution with non-integer degrees of freedom (eg. $\nu $ = 1.5) to model some observed data. My simplest idea is to use the usual Student-$t$ ratio formula: $ x = \frac{N(0,1)}{\sqrt {\chi^2_{ \nu }/ \nu } }  $. Subsequently, to generate random samples from $ \chi_{\nu}^2 $ generate its inverse cdf and sample with a uniform distribution but the inverse cdf is difficult to calculate for non-integer $\nu$. Is there a simplification ?

Comment: You can write down the density and CDF of $t(\nu)$. Can't you do inverse transform sampling or rejection sampling with this?

Comment: Use a computer language such as R:  `rt(1000,1.5)` will give you a thousand values.

Comment: Henry:  I got a list of samples from R which I'll start some tests on, looks promising.    Jose: I don't actually have useable expressions for the cdf especially for the fractional-$\nu$ inverse Student cdf.